# What was Uncle Nicky referring to when he said 'Half past the Vatican'?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, angela-anaconda

In a flashback in the *Angela Anaconda* episode *the Curse of Baby Lulu*, 'Uncle' Nicky Abatti tells of how, when he was dancing, his watch starts to beep- he says to his dance partners

> "It's half past the Vatican, that means I gotta go pick up my nephew Johnny from his friend Angela's house."

I'm assuming "half past the Vatican" refers to half-past a specific hour- can anyone help clarify which hour?

Comment: The museums close at 18:00, 20:00 or 22:30 on friday I believe, would it match? It can also be the catholic hours for the masses?